# wso2 esb xpath substring-before special characters Carriage Return

Tags: xpath, wso2, carriage-return, wso2-esb

In wso2 esb,proxy service, I am trying to get a string with xpath substring-before who extract 1 line stop by an Carriage Return (cr). here is my property.

```
<property name="str_id" expression="fn:substring-before(get-property('INPUT_MESSAGE'),'&#13;')"/>
```

When I save my proxy configuration from the web administration console, the carriage return character is replace by a white space. When I use an other editor like notepad, I have no problem, the carriage return is not replace. But the problem, if I restart the wso2 esb server, it replace it by an white space again.

Any idea of the problem ? Is that an bug?

Best regards,
Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carriage return will systematically be removed from your mediation's xml definition.

One solution could be to import a text resource containing carriage return in ESB gov registry and use this resource in your xpath expression :

- create a text file **CR.txt** with your text editor and **insert** a single character with ascii code **13** (use hexa view for exemple, don't just press 'return' or you may insert ascii code 10)
- go to esb console, choose **Browse** under **Registry**, go to **/_system/governance/trunk**, choose **Add resource** and updload your file
- change your xpath like this : `<property name="str_id" expression="fn:substring-before(get-property('INPUT_MESSAGE'),syn:get-property('gov:trunk/CR.txt'))"/>`